# How to add custom authentication to aws s3 download of large files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to figure out how to implement these requirements for S3 downloads:

- Signed URL (links should become invalid after some amount of time).
- Download only 1 time - any other requests to the same URL should fail.
- Need to restrict downloads to the user/browser who made the request to generate the signed URL - no other user should be able to download.
- Be able to deal with large files (ideally, streaming, just like when someone downloads directly from a standard S3 access point).

Things that I've tried:

- S3 Object Lambda + Access Point

  - Generate pre-signed URL to lambda access point, this works well.
  - Make use of S3 object metadata to store download state / restrict downloads to just 1 time. This works well.
  - No way to access user-agent or requestor's IP.
  - Large files are a problem. Timeout has been configured to 15 minutes (the max), but request still times out much earlier. This was done with NodeJS.
- Lambda + Lambda URL

  - Pre-signed URL is generated and passed to lambda URL as encoded param - the lambda makes the request if auth/validation passes. This approach seems to work fine.
  - Can use same approach of leveraging S3 object metadata to limit downloads to just 1 time.
  - User-agent and requestor IP is available, this is great.
  - Large files are a problem. I've tried NodeJS and it behaves the same as the S3 Object Lambda (eventually times out, even earlier than the configured time), Also implemented the Java streaming handler but it dies with an "out of memory" error, even when I bump the memory up to 3GB (the file is only 1GB and I thought streaming would get around the memory problem anyway). I've tried several ways to stream (Java 11), but it really seems like the streaming handler is not really streaming, but buffering somewhere outside of the lambda.

I'm now unsure if AWS lambda will be able to handle all of these requirements, but I would really like to know if others might have ideas, or if I'm missing something.

Comment: "any other requests to the same URL should fail" Even if the download is interrupted and the browser attempts to resume the download?

Comment: That's a good question. I think in that case, we'd want to allow the user to resume the download, but if that then requires a lambda (or something) to serve the content, then probably not (due to the limitations of lambdas that I've experienced so far ... mainly, the inability to stream responses). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Option C - Cloudfront  (+S3 origin) + Lamda @Edge - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-cloudfront-trigger-events.html